# Question about Perceptron activation threshold

Tags: neural-network, perceptron, activation-function

I have a Perceptron written in Javascript that works fine, code below. My question is about the threshold in the activation function. Other code I have seen has something like `if (sum > 0) {return 1} else {return 0}.` My perceptron only works with `if (sum > 1) {return 1} else {return 0}.` Why is that? Full code below.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function Perceptron(numInputs=2) {
        let weights = Array.from({length: numInputs}, () => 2 * Math.random() - 1);  // [-1, 1)
        this.learningRate = 0.5;

        this.train = function (inputs, goal) {
            // feed forward
            let guess = this.predict(inputs);

            // back propagation
            let error = goal - guess;
            if (error !== 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < weights.length; i += 1) {
                    weights[i] += this.learningRate * error * inputs[i];
                }
            }
        }

        this.predict = function (inputs) {
            // transfer function
            let sumProducts = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
                sumProducts += inputs[i] * weights[i];
            }

            // activation function, threshold = 1
            return (sumProducts >= 1) ? 1 : 0;  // <-- this is the line I have a question about
        }
    }
    
    // train
    let data = [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]
    ];

    let p = new Perceptron(2);
    
    const epochs = 20;
    for (let i = 0; i < epochs; i += 1) {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
        p.train(data[r].slice(0, 2), data[r].slice(-1));
    }

    // test
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        let inputs = data[i].slice(0, 2);
        console.log(`inputs = ${inputs}; output = ${p.predict(inputs)}`);
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your perceptron lacks a bias term, your equation is of form `SUM_i w_i x_i,` instead of `SUM_i w_i x_i + b`. With the functional form you have it is impossible to separate points, where the separating hyperplane does not cross the origin (and yours does not). Alternatively you can add a column of "1s" to your data, it will serve the same purpose, as the corresponding `w_i` will just behave as `b` (since all `x_i` will be 1)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a bias term as `sumProducts += inputs[i] * weights[i] + this.bias;` I noticed that the bias must be pretty low, like 0.1, for the perceptron to work like it did before adding the bias term. However, even with the bias the perceptron still does not work at all when I change `return (sumProducts >= 1) ? 1 : 0;` to `return (sumProducts >= 0) ? 1 : 0;`.  Still hoping to get an understanding why. Thanks!

Comment: It does work with a negative bias. -1 works nicely. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Bias should be *learned*, not fixed. The update rules is identical to the weight, just lacks "* inputs[i]" (as described in the answer it is equivalent to having a constant input of 1, and multiplying by 1 does nothing).

Comment: Now I understand, and have it working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else following this question, here is the final code. Thanks to @lejlot for helping!

```js
/*jslint for:true, long:true, devel:true, this:true */
/*jshint esversion: 6*/

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function Perceptron(numInputs = 2) {
        this.weights = Array.from({length: numInputs}, () => 2 * Math.random() - 1);  // [-1, 1)
        this.learningRate = 0.5;
        this.bias = 1;

        this.train = function (inputs, goal) {
            // feed forward
            let guess = this.predict(inputs);

            // back propagation
            let error = goal - guess;
            if (error !== 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i += 1) {
                    this.weights[i] += error * inputs[i] * this.learningRate;
                }
                
                // Bias should be learned, not fixed. The update rules is
                // identical to the weight, just lacks "* inputs[i]" (as
                // described in the answer it is equivalent to having a constant
                // input of 1, and multiplying by 1 does nothing).
                this.bias += error * this.learningRate;
            }
        };

        this.predict = function (inputs) {
            // transfer function
            let sumProducts = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
                sumProducts += inputs[i] * this.weights[i];
            }

            // Your perception lacks a bias term, your equation if of form
            // SUM_i w_i x_i, instead of SUM_i w_i x_i + b. With the
            // functional form you have it is impossible to separate points,
            // where the separating hyperplane does not cross the origin
            // (and yours does not). Alternatively you can add a column of
            // "1s" to your data, it will serve the same purpose, as the
            // corresponding w_i will just behave as "b" (since all x_i will
            // be 1)
            sumProducts += this.bias;

            // activation function
            return (sumProducts >= 0) ? 1 : 0;
        };
    }

    // train - boolean AND
    let data = [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]
    ];

    let p = new Perceptron(2);

    const epochs = 100;

    for (let i = 0; i < epochs; i += 1) {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
        p.train(data[r].slice(0, 2), data[r].slice(-1));
    }

    // test
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        let inputs = data[i].slice(0, 2);
        console.log(`inputs = ${inputs}; output = ${p.predict(inputs)}`);
    }
}());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).